# If I run boot repair will I lose everything in my hard drive?

Tags: boot, boot-repair, initramfs

My computer won't boot to ubuntu. What I get instead is

```
BusyBox v.1.18.5-1ubuntu4.1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in. Commands.

(Initramfs)
```

Answer (score 3):

Boot repair won't delete anything on your hard drive. It will just repair boot issues by making GRUB the default bootloader in the Master Boot Record